# Translate django default ?page=1 to ?side=1 (Norwegian)

Tags: django, django-urls, django-pagination

Im trying to find a way to change django default `?page=1` to `?side=1`, or maybe better, `/side/1`

This is my listview:

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "news_list"
    paginate_by = 18
    queryset = Entry.published.all().order_by('-start_publication')
```

I have tried like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/side/(?P<page>\d+)/$', 'news.views.EntryListView'),
    url(r'^$', EntryListView.as_view(), name="news"),
)
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `?page=1` to `?side=1` you can add the `page_kwarg` attribute to your class.

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "news_list"
    paginate_by = 18
    queryset = Entry.published.all().order_by('-start_publication')
    page_kwarg = 'side'
```

There is no reason that that `/side/1/` would not match your URL pattern without overriding the `page_kwarg`, maybe you missed the trailing slash while testing?

Comment: page_kwarg works great! Not sure why my /side/1/ does not work. I have tried with `(?P<page>\d+)` and (?P<page_obj>\d+), but I only get `Page not found` when I try, but `?side=2` works fine. Thank you.